# check if all the digits of the given number are different

Tags: python, digits

I want to create a 4-digit number between 1000 and 10000 with different digits, but I am a bit inexperienced as I am new to this stuff. Can you help me?

```
import random

number = random.choice(range(1000,10000))


print(number)
```

Comment: What do you mean by different digits?  Do you mean you don't want the digits 0 thru 9 to be repeated; or do you want to select a sequence of 4-digit numbers that don't repeat?

Comment: “I am a bit inexperienced”. Fine, fair play.  What *research* have you done to try and work this out on your own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import random

a = 0
while a == 0:
    a, b, c, d = random.sample(range(10), 4)
k = 1000*a + 100*b + 10*c + d
print(k)
```

Comment: You can directly select the digits to avoid 0 in the first position, [without trial end error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73093812/16343464) ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the digits of the number and check if that digit is in the number more than once.

```py
def different_digits(num):
    for d in str(num):
        if str(num).count(d) > 1:
            return False
    return True

print(different_digits(1234)) # True
print(different_digits(1224)) # False
```

This can even be simplified with `all`:

```py
def different_digits(num):
    return all(str(num).count(d) == 1 for d in str(num))

print(different_digits(1234)) # True
print(different_digits(1224)) # False
```

---

Now to get the 4-digit number just use a `while` loop:

```py
x = random.randint(1000, 9999)
while not different_digits(x):
    x = random.randint(1000, 9999)
```

Comment: but I get the number randomly from the system, I don't enter it myself. @the-thonnu

Comment: @hamsi, *"but I get the number ... from the system"*. Hold on, you wrote in the question you want to **create** it. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

Using a direct selection of the digits, without any trial and error:

```
import random

s = '123456789'
# select first digit
a = random.sample(s, 1)
# select last 3 digits
b = random.sample(list(set(s).difference(a))+['0'], 3)

out = int(''.join(a+b))
```

Example output: `6784`

Comment: Nice answer. I prefer `s = range(1, 10)` and `out = a*10**len(b) + sum(num*10**idx for idx, num in enumerate(b))`, but these are minor quibbles.

Comment: @jpp I don't remember which one is the most efficient